# Best Azure Website Service for mobile clients

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Which Azure Service should i use for hosting a website which is going to be used only from mobile clients. Secure communication between website and client is important as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This community helps programmers and DevOps with their daily tasks related to programming. When you have specific question related to programming with concrete issue which you cannot solve, you are mostly welcome to ask your question here!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Azure website with bootstrap or mobile angular UI. You can add certificate to website for ssl security.